# how to disable display custom field in page template?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created my custom fields through code and then I registered it with this code:

```
/**
 * Content blocks for all pages
 */
$location_page = new ACF_Group_Location;
$location_page->add_rule( 'post_type', 'page');

$location_slots = new ACF_Group_Location;
$location_slots->add_rule( 'post_type', 'slots' );

$location_card = new ACF_Group_Location;
$location_card->add_rule( 'post_type', 'card' );



ACF_Group::create( 'content-blocks', __( 'Content blocks', 'dw' ) )
    ->add_location( $location_page )
    ->add_location( $location_slots )
    ->add_location( $location_card )
    ->set_attr( 'label_placement', 'top' )
    ->set_attr( 'hide_on_screen', array( 'the_content', 'comments' ) )
    ->add_fields( array(
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Content blocks', 'dw' ),
            'name' => 'cb',
            'type' => 'flexible_content',
            'button_label' => __( 'Add content block', 'dw' ),
            'layouts' => $cb
        ),
    )
)->register();
```

add_rule() includes:

```
public function add_rule( $param, $value, $operator = '==' ) {
        $this->rules[] = compact( 'param', 'value', 'operator' );

        return $this;
    }
```

and my question is what code do I need to add if I wanna disable them on my page template?

Answer (score 0):

So you're using ACF programatically using [this](https://github.com/RadoslavGeorgiev/acf-code-helper/wiki#step-3-locations)

instead of adding your custom fields to all pages and then try to disable it for a particular template just add your custom field group to the template you need.

```
<?php
add_action( 'register_acf_groups', 'my_theme_register_acf_groups' );
function mytheme_register_acf_groups() {
    ACF_Group::create( 'my_group', 'My Group' )
        ->add_location_rule( 'post_type', 'page' )
        ->add_location_rule( 'page_template', 'template-contact.php' ) // <- see here
        ->set_attr( 'label_placement', 'left' )
        ->add_fields(array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Test Field',
                'name'  => 'test_field',
                'type'  => 'text'
            ),
        ))
        ->register();
}
```

Comment: but I need to remove it only from one page template, when I use post_type => page it will be shown on each page I have